# How to configure KDE apps for dark mode on XFCE desktop

Tags: kde, themes, xfce, 22.04

I am using XFCE desktop and have some problems with using a dark desktop theme in KDE apps. I have tried different values for QT theme environment variables. It works partially:

[image: kate]

I think I need to modify KDE:s default theme to a dark theme, but the appearance panel in KDE system settings is empty.

[image: kde system settings]

I am currently on 22.04

### Update

I installed kde-plasma-desktop to add the missing entries in KDE system settings, and was able to enable breeze-dark. Now I wonder, what package among all these packages was the package that enabled the KDE appearance panel?